# Gas confined in a box

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, ideal-gas, gas

I have a gas with $N$ particles in $D$ dimensions confined in a box, I have written the Hamiltonian as
$$
H = \sum_{p=1}^N\sum_{d=1}^D\frac{p^2_{pd}}{2m}+V_0[\theta(-q_{pd})+\theta({q_{pd}-L_d})]
$$
since the box has length $L_d$ in the $d$th direction. Also $V_0\rightarrow\infty$. How can I find the number of microstates of this system using the microcanonical formalism? The question says something about a relation between $V_0$ and $E$, specifically that I should consider a different definition of $\theta$ and impose that the turning points of the gas in the system are $0$ and $L_d$, but I have no clue what this means. The definition of the $\theta$ function is
$$
\theta=\left\{\begin{matrix}
 &0\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,x<-\epsilon \\ 
 & \frac{x+\epsilon}{2\epsilon}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,-\epsilon<x<\epsilon\\ 
 & 1 \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,x<1
\end{matrix}\right.
$$

Answer (score 1):

The way I know it one just sums ver all available positions and momenta of all particles to get the partition function. This can be achieved by instead computing the phase space volume and give it some prefactors which you probably know. The phase space volume is just the integral over all allowed positions and momenta, so we basically just replaced the sum with an integral. So let's talk about the phase space volume.

I don't really know why one should need the specific definition of theta other than the usual one, so I will right now argue with the normal one and at the end say something about the one you have provided. It goes like this: Because of $V_0$ goes to infinity no particle with a finite energy can classically leave the box. Otherwise there is no restriction to the position, so the position integral gives $L_d^D$ for each particle, so all particles give a $L_d^{ND}$. The restriction on the momenta is that the kinetic energy (normally the total energy, but for all allowed positions the potential is zero) of all particles combined should be smaller than $E$, i.e. $\sum_{p=1}^N \sum_{d=1}^D \frac{p_{pd}^2}{2m}<E$. This is the equation of a sphere in momentum space in $ND$ dimensions with radius $\sqrt{2mE}$. The volume of such a higher dimensional sphere is known.

So finally just multiply $L_d^{ND}$ with the volume of the hypersphere and you have the phase space volume, multiply with the right factors that take you from phase space volume to microcanonical partition function and you are finished.

**What happens when we use the definition you provided?** This makes everything more complicated because now we cannot just separate position integral and momentum integral. Now the upper limit for the kinetic energy is $E$ minus the potential term and there is a small region where this potential term is not zero so the radius of our "momentum sphere" now depends on position in the small region at the boundary of the box where the potential is neither 0 nor infinite. I would suggest completing the momentum integral first: Is again just is the volume of the corresponding sphere, but now with radius $\sqrt{2m(E-V)}$ where $V$ is the potential that is build from the $\theta$'s. For the position integral you seperate it into an integral over the region where $V=0$, where you can proceed as before, and the rest where $V\ne 0$. I will now mention that you are probably expected to take the limit $\epsilon \to 0$, in which this additional term will just vanish, so I don't know how far one should actually go to try and get an explicit expression for it. But you can at least try to go a little bit further and integrate over all the $q_{pd}$ that are outside the box (in the region where the $\theta$'s are neither 0 nor 1). The integral should go from the point where the $\theta$ is 0 but starts increasing to the turning point where it is $E/V_0$ which will go to 0 as well when we let $V_0$ go to infinity. One can write down the result for these integrals but it appears to me to be rather cumbersome and I doubt that you are actually supposed to do that. Instead you should just argue that the integration region for these additional terms gets smaller and smaller while the integrand is a bounded function (bounded above by the volume of the sphere with radius $\sqrt{2mE}$ because the sphere with radius $\sqrt{2m(E-V)}$ has a smaller volume for positive $V$ which is the case here) so these integrals will all tend to zero.

If you do want to calculate it explicitely until the end you will have to "count" how many of these regions there are for each $k$ when $k$ is the number of coordinates that are "outside the box", i.e. somewhere where the potential is not zero. These regions are just faces of the corresponding $ND$-dimensional hypercube if I am not mistaken and you can look up the numbers of faces [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercube#Faces). If you have no idea why that should be the case here is a small examplification:

Imagine you only had one particle in 3 dimensions. For each coordinate there is the $V=0$-region $(\epsilon,L_d-\epsilon)$ (i.e. where the potential is zero), and the region where $0<V<V_0$, which are the two intervals $[-\epsilon,\epsilon]$ or $[L_d-\epsilon, L_d+\epsilon]$. There are multiple cases now: First case: All 3 coordinates, say $x,y,z$, are in the $V=0$-region. This means the coordinate vector is in the cube $(\epsilon,L_d-\epsilon)^3$. Second case: One of them is not in the $V=0$-region, the other two are. This means the two coordinates that are together in the $V=0$-region together come from $(\epsilon,L_d-\epsilon)^2$, the last coordinate from $[-\epsilon,\epsilon]$ or $[L_d-\epsilon, L_d+\epsilon]$. Alltogether the set where the coordinate vector could be can be visually interpreted of a thin layer (thickness $2\epsilon$) on one of the (two-dimensional) faces of the cube $(\epsilon,L_d-\epsilon)^3$. Third case: Now the coordinate vector is in something like $(\epsilon,L_d-\epsilon)\times[-\epsilon,\epsilon]^2$ or any other combination where two coordinates are not in a $V=0$-region. These are all the "one-dimensional faces", i.e. the edges of the cube $(\epsilon,L_d-\epsilon)^3$. Fourth case: None of the coordinates are in the $V=0$-region. This corresponds to the "zero-dimensional faces", i.e. corners, of the cube.

I personally think this whole part is very unnecessary and you are probably not supposed to go through the whole computation of that part just to set it to zero in the end.

I hope you are familiar enough with the procedure to understand what I am talking about. If you are confused by the part with the regions and the cubes don't worry, just take the explanation before that which didn't use "your" definition of the $\theta$.